# Lombok, use only getter setter not equals or tostring

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

Because we dont use `tostring` or `equals` and it reduces `coverage`.

So we need to disable lombok for `tostring`, `equals`

Is there any way?

For getter

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
```

i can do this but for others, what can i do?

And as i understood,

```
@lombok.Accessors(chain = true, fluent = true)
```

this is also for getter setter

Comment: Why do you think code coverage going down for this reason is a bad thing?

Comment: So you don't use any persistence framework or hash based collections in your application? Esp. equals and hashCode methods are used by a lot of Java internal methods and classes.

Comment: @christopher the alternative would be to write tests for those methods, but there is no point in testing lombok's generated code. The lombok people have their own tests, surely. vegan should be writing unit tests that test vegan's code, not lombok's code.

Comment: Or change your view on code coverage and accept that it is a single metric in a chorus of metrics, and that number going down isnt objectively bad

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736045/lombok-generated-code-can-not-be-ignored-on-coverage can you look @christopher David Conrad

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you're using for coverage, but we have enabled a lombok setting that prevents it from affecting our coverage. Create a **lombok.config** file at the top level of your project with this:

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

The first line is optional; it just tells lombok to stop searching for other config files. The second line causes lombok to add an annotation to the methods it creates marking them as being lombok generated. For the coverage tool we use, jacoco, that prevents it from taking these methods into consideration when calculating the coverage.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736045/lombok-generated-code-can-not-be-ignored-on-coverage please look

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do it.

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class SomeClass {
...
}
```