# Lombok generated code can not be ignored on coverage

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok

Here I asked the question:

[Lombok, use only getter setter not equals or tostring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52667771/lombok-use-only-getter-setter-not-equals-or-tostring/52668460#52668460)

I did not want to comment there, because it was very old.

What I want is, I want the code which is generated by lombok to be ignored during coverage of `inteljidea` and also `sonar.`

As suggestion in my previous question that I linked , I added this

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

I added this to root ,then rebuilded recoveraged.

But for that class

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ApiModel(parent = BaseApiResponse.class)
public class SaveObligation extends Base{

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    List<LegalObligationDTO> legalObligations;


    public SaveLegalObligatione(String id, List<LegalObligationDTO> legalObligations) {
        super(id, true);
        this.legalObligations = legalObligations;
    }
}



inteljidea shows all green (which means covered) except those lines:

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
```

because of lombok I guess.

What can I do for this?

Also , i tried this

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addJavaxGeneratedAnnotation = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

For intelj, i dont use different tool coverage. Its own coverage.

By the way, `intelj` shows like that. But also the code is going to sonarqube so also there will be `analysed` for `coverage`.

This is buildgradle

```
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:+'
```

Comment: Hi vegan. You added that configuration where? In `lombok.config`?

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well. Did you ever find a resolution on this? Code coverage in intellij is showing 'lines uncovered' on data / equals , despite the annotations (supposedly) being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Lombok works in compile time.
For more information see [Here](http://notatube.blogspot.com/2010/12/project-lombok-creating-custom.html) for example

So that the bytecode already contains Lombok generated transformations.

Coverage tools, on the other hand, usually work in runtime performing bytecode manipulation).

So, it doesn't make sense to configure Lombok to exclude certain code in coverage, but rather depends on the coverage tool of your choice.

Sonar works at the later phase by gathering reports generated by the coverage tools and sending them to Sonar server.

So I think you should check whether its possible to configure your code coverage tool.

Having said that, probably this code should be called in unit tests - implicitly, not directly, I'm not suggesting unit-testing of lombok generated code.

Comment: It will be very hard for us to call those setters because we have hundreds of. So for now, we need temporary solution, to ignore those.

Comment: In this case maybe it worth to use automated bean testing. https://github.com/codebox/javabean-tester is one example, there exist others as well

Comment: Jacoco, for instance, ignores code annotated with `@lombok.Generated` automatically since v0.8.0.

Comment: Lombok works in compile time. Coverage is done at runtime. The coverage tool looks at reports generated when the tests were run, **but** it will ignore code annotated as having been generated by Lombok. So, the `lombok.config` settings are needed to get Lombok to add the necessary annotations.